# lower bound number of roots of polynomial with coefficients in prime field

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, roots

Assume I am given a polynomial $f$ with coefficients from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (for prime $p$) of degree $d$.

We know that if $f$ is not the constant zero function, then it has at most $d$ roots.

**Question:** Is it true that $f$ always has *exactly* $d$ roots?

If so, then how to show this? If not, then a counter-example would be appreciated.

Comment: Exactly $d$ roots in what ring or field? $x^2+1$ is a polynomial with no roots in any $\Bbb Z_p$ or $\Bbb Q_p$ with $p\equiv3\pmod4$.

Comment: The polynomial is from $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$, so the evaluations (hence also the roots) are in the field, or not? So from your answer I understand that in both cases the answer is "no"?

Comment: The answer is "no", just like it would be over the integers or rationals or reals. Indeed, the answer being "yes" is essentially the same as saying the underlying ring is an algebraically closed field.